# Custom Matching Rule in Lead Conversion

Tags: lead-conversion, duplicate-matching-rule

While lead Conversion, when we are using 'Choose Existing' the matching accounts are currently shown based on the standard matching rule. We need to override this to use a custom matching.
I have created an account matching rule and duplicate rule with the custom logic. Also 'Enable Validation on Lead Conversion' is checked. This the matching accounts are not showing.

We are using person account in our org.

Comment: 1. Can you check the custom duplicate/matching is active on account or not. 2. if it is active then check the matching rule condition satisfied or not. Refer the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLyDNfUS_QU

Comment: Can you please review the considerations for duplicate rules using this link https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The duplicate rule/matching rules are active and the 'Potential Duplicate' component is displaying the duplicates as expected. The issue is only in Lead Conversion screen the account matches are still shown based on the standard duplicate rule alone.